# How to inspect element which is in <a> tag to select drop down list from menu

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

```
<a ui-sref="about({id:1})" href="/ms/about/1">Over</a>
```

Pleases tell me for above mentioned link how to inspect element to click on drop down sub menu.

Comment: Appreciated if you can shared your trial code and exception if you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below combination :
Action class with method mouseover or clickandhold action to get the suboptions.
Action action = new Action(driver);

## action.clickAndHold(By.linktext("Over"));